# Ball rolling and turning effect with SpriteKit

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have created a ball node, and applied the texture images from my 3d model. I have captured totally 6 images, 3 images (with having 120deg) for rolling around x axis, and other 3 images for rolling around y axis. I want sprite kit to simulate it with following code below.When i apply impulse, it starts sliding instead rolling and when it collides to sides, then it starts turning but again not rolling. Normally, depending on the impulse on the ball, it should turn and roll together sometimes. The effect on "8 ball pool game" balls can be an example which i want to get a result.

```
var ball = SKSpriteNode()
var textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
var textureArray = [SKTexture]()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "white")
    for i in 0... textureAtlas.textureNames.count {
        let name = "ball_\(i).png"
        textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name))
    }

    ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: textureAtlas.textureNames[0])
    ball.size = CGSize(width: ballRadius*2, height: ballRadius*2)
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: -ballRadius/2-20, y: -ballRadius-20)
    ball.zPosition = 0

    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.3
    ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true

    addChild(ball)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply angular impulse to get it to rotate

`node.physicsBody!.applyAngularImpulse(1.0)`

Comment: Dear Knight0fDragon, thanks for your response, i have already given a same impulse with following code as in "applyAngularImpulse(1.0)";    `ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector, at: CGPoint(x:12, y: 0) )` .When we consider x,y,z axis on the center of the ball node, with angularImpulse, no problem to turn it to right and left, but i want to give an impulse which will provide him to roll (push or reverse effect to the ball), how i can apply it? Depending on it, it should seen as rolling (around y or x axis) instead turning right or left (around z axis)

Comment: Is it possible to use 3d node in Spritekit scene and apply force on z axis, allowing ball to roll or reverse?